# how to pass the value and show title list?

Tags: php

i echo something like the following in a file(test.php).

```
....
201105
201106
201107
201108
201109
201110
....
```

the code output it:

```
$months = 10; //count of months 
$date = date_create( 'now' );
echo date_format( $date, 'Y M' );
for ( $i = 0; $i < $months; $i++ ) {
    date_sub( $date , date_interval_create_from_date_string( '1 months' ) );
    echo date_format( $date, 'Y M' );
}
```

the above is the year-month archive. now i want to when the user click the year-month. then in the current page shows each articles' title with list that belong to the year-month. i know i should use a passed value into my database query to select out each articles' title.each article created time is as this `15806927473`. but i don't know how to passed the value. when the user click the year-month. and use the passed value in my sql query.
thank you.

the sql query code:

```
$result=mysql_query("select title from node where  a > created_time > b ");
```

how to rite the a and b. and make the passed value time compares with  this style  `15806927473`.

the database is mysql.

Answer (score 1):

The `158...` value is most likely a unix timestamp, which is the number of seconds since Jan 1/1970. You don't specify which database you're on, so can't help you out properly. However, assuming you're on MySQL, you can easily convert between timestamps and date/time values with `FROM_UNIXTIME()` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

You don't specify how your year/month values are generated, but it's not particularly hard to do some string manipulation to turn '201105' into '2011-05-01 00:00:00', which you can pass into MySQL as a date/time value to do comparisons in the database.

As for your a > c > b construct, that's a syntax error. You'd want it to look like:

```
... WHERE (a > created_time) AND (a > b)
```

Comment: i think the a, b is knowen. because a is the first day of the month.b is the last day of the month. but each month's last day maybe different. how to passed them?

Comment: Don't do it based on days-of-month. Try doing something like `where (Month(created_time) = 5) and (Year(created_time) = 2011)`, which eliminates the need to calculate actual days.

Comment: MySQL has a very good selection of date/time manipulation/formatting functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html